# How can I use an MVC5 asp.net Identity user database for asp.net 5 services concurrently

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I have a web site build using .net Framework 4.8 and MVC5 which is using Identity 2 for authentication/user management.

Now I am creating a new application for a REST API written in .net 5 using JWT authentication and I want to use the same user database for both (SQL tables accessed using Microsoft EF).

I've successfully managed to modify the schema of the users table and I can authenticate users in the new REST service but during login the password stored in the database is rehashed and updated so that it will no longer work in the old MVC5 app.

I'm trying to force the new .net 5 app to use the old (V2) .net 4.8 hashed passwords without changing them to the new V3 format. In the .net 5 app I have added the following line to the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) of Startup.cs but it does not have any effect. The password still gets updated in the database, leaving the users on the old app unable to log in.

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);
```

I have tried to add this before and after the call to AddIdentity which looks like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

It makes no difference. The PasswordHasherOptions do not appear to be effective.

I am using Autofac as my DI for the .net 5 app, if that makes any difference.

Comment: What do you mean `MVC 5`? Do you mean ASP.NET Core MVC 5 perhaps? .NET 5 is actually .NET *Core* 5. You can't mix .NET Framework and .NET Core code, and `ASP.NET MVC 5` refers to an old version built on top of .NET Framework.

Comment: By MVC5 app I mean a web site built using asp.net Framework 4.8. I'll clarify my question accordingly. And I'm not trying to mix the two frameworks. I'm trying to allow the two individual applications to use the same users database.

Comment: Maybe, if you used Identity Server or any other OpenID service as the common authentication service. ASP.NET MVC 5 was released in 2013 - 8 years ago. In the meantime the acceptable password hashing algorithms have changed and some have been broken. The Identity framework has changed a lot in the last 7 years

Comment: I'd certainly consider using Identity Server etc. if that was an option. At the moment I'm forced to stick with the old system for a while at least. And during this time I'm hoping to be able to use this backwards compatibility option which looks like it should be available. If I figure out what's causing it not to behave as expected.